# Hungarian babel makes English headers strange

Tags: header-footer, babel

I am writing a `book` mainly in English but it contains substantial Hungarian text, so I would use

```
\usepackage[magyar,english]{babel}
```

However, this makes chapter numbers in the headers look weird. Rather than

> CHAPTER 3. FOOBAR

I get

> 3. CHAPTER. FOOBAR

(the logical thing in Hungarian). Is there any way to get the proper English behaviour back without using `fancyhdr` or the like?

**EDIT:** an example

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[magyar,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Foobar}
Blah\pagebreak

Blah\pagebreak
\chapter{Barfoo}
Blah\pagebreak

Blah
\end{document}
```

**Edit 2:** Log for this input (babel-relevant parts)

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2013/12/03 3.9h The Babel package

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/babel-hungarian/magyar.ldf
Language: magyar 2007/10/19 v1.5 Magyar support from the babel v3.7 system

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2013/12/03 3.9h Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count88
\U@D=\dimen103
)
Package babel Info: Making ` an active character on input line 2731.
\c@footnote@add=\count89
\c@footnote@ch=\count90
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
Language: english 2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
\l@british = a dialect from \language\l@english 
\l@UKenglish = a dialect from \language\l@english 
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american 
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british 
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british 
))
```

**Edit 3:** As it was pointed out by Paul Gaborit, the very problem in the question is solved by loading `\usepackage[spanish,magyar,english]{babel}`. However, this seems to work by `spanish.ldf` inhibiting `magyar.ldf` in changing the header style, so `\usepackage[spanish,magyar]` produces headers in the English/Spanish word order rather than the Hungarian one. Does anyone know how to resolve *this*?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you make a full minimal example?

Comment: I think is not hard with `fancyhdr`, but if you dont want to use that package, an option is write with `memoir` class, this class has own commands to custom headers (and headings) style ...

Comment: Try to change the other of the languages in the `babel`.

Comment: @juanuni I know it isn't too hard with fancyhdr. It's just bugging that something that really has nothing to do with the chapter titles messes this up.

Comment: I think is possible without `fancyhdr`, but maybe is some hard ...

Comment: @Sigur magyar&ngerman produces the same error, I only have these three languages installed with my latex

Comment: This is buried very deep in the hungarian localization file. Is there any reason why you don't want to use a decent header-footer package?

Comment: `magyar` has lots of options. On http://www.math.bme.hu/latex/ you can find its manual (in Hungarian).

Comment: Sorry if that was confusing, I used the `book` class (indeed, nothing really comes up in `report`)

Comment: Try `\usepackage[spanish,magyar,main=english]{babel}`...

Comment: @PaulGaborit Nice one. English headers are now as they should be. However, the English form persists for Hungarian texts as well then, so it's kinda half-solution. (I suppose `spanish` and `magyar` share some poor implementation that causes this.) 

I wanted in the long run write a `custom` package to bundle up everything I need to typeset in the languages I use regularly: it seems that it will necessarily come short at this point.

Comment: Do you really want to change the style of the header mid-document?

Comment: That's funny - `magyar` rereads the class file doing some dangerous readjustments and at a very bad place. Under these circumstances, anything could happen! As to the behavior with `spanish`, it's related to that, because some macros are reread with new catcodes and compared with the values as first read at `\documentclass`. A test fails because of this mismatch. There is nothing wrong with `spanish` at this respect, then (well, I've discovered a minor bug - a misplaced line - but that's unrelated).

Comment: @Johannes_B No, I wanted to write a package that I can just plug in at the beginning of a document and it does the formatting I'd do anyway; but this doesn't quite work with `babel`. Also, `\usepackage[spanish,magyar]`, meant to produce the Hungarian layout, stucks at the English (or equivalently, Spanish) one, and nothing seems to revert it.

Comment: You want to have a package `attilaszabo`, and select the langugage (and hence header style) for  the document, no matter which languages are actually used? Seems a bit more explanation is needed :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B I actually have one such package :) It is for including stuff you always need (like AMS stuff, `geometry` etc.). Also, I put in `babel` specifications together with other language specific stuff (whether or not to use `frenchspacing` etc.): I figured out how to deal with this.

What is more interesting is that`\usepackage[spanish,magyar]` fixes the Spanish(=English) style for the header, so Hungarian words appear in the wrong arrangement. It doesn't seem I could overcome this one.

Comment: Hint: Add this information (and all other extra info to understand what is going on) to the question. It will be back on top of the main site and people become aware of it once more.

Comment: Thanks :) I guess the only important issue is that `spanish.ldf` inhibits `magyar.ldf` in this part

Answer (score 2):

Use the `classmod=unchanged` option of the `magyar.ldf`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\PassOptionsToPackage{defaults=hu-min,classmod=unchanged}{magyar.ldf}
\usepackage[magyar,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
Text\newpage Text
\end{document}
```